# Closet 3-way switch or toggle

Tags: switch, closet

Is there such a thing as a closet door three way. In other words, I have two large closet doors that close one to the right and one to the left. I have power inside the closet and would like to turn on a light either by opening the right or left door. Instead of a "three way, I also thought of a toggle type switch that could be mounted above the doors that would trip on if opened either way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really a 3-way: that would be the light turns on if either for us open, **but not both**. You are looking for two standard switches, wired in parallel. This way, the light will be on if either, or both doors are open.

Comment: Agree with Doxy, but a picture of what you have exactly may be helpful to verify.

Comment: Yeah -- what do you have in there right now? This is pretty easy to do with two parallel switches...

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, buy a pair of physical proximity switches, mount one for each door, and wire them in parallel. That way, either door, or both, will turn the light on when you open it.

Sample item:
[door switch](https://smile.amazon.com/Lee-Electric-209DN-600-Watt-Switch/dp/B001EVKA8G/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474296746&sr=8-1&keywords=door%20-%20activated%20light%20switch)

[image]